# proguard error with parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, proguard

I am getting the following errors when I use Proguard with Parse Push:

> [2014-08-28 14:09:35 - PicturePlay] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
>   [2014-08-28 14:09:35 - PicturePlay] proguard.ParseException: Expecting keyword 'class', >'interface', or 'enum' before '-include' in argument number 5
>   [2014-08-28 14:09:35 - PicturePlay]
>     at proguard.ConfigurationParser.readNextWord(ConfigurationParser.java:1133)
>   [2014-08-28 14:09:35 - PicturePlay]
>     at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseClassSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:514)
>   [2014-08-28 14:09:35 - PicturePlay]
>     at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parse(ConfigurationParser.java:151)
>   [2014-08-28 14:09:35 - PicturePlay]
>     at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:484)

The Proguard config I am using in proguard-properties.txt is:

> -dontwarn com.parse.**
>
> -keep class com.parse.** { *; }
>
> -libraryjars \libs\Parse-1.5.0.jar
>
> -keepattributes Annotation
>
> -keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
>
> -keep public class * extends android.app.Application
>
> -keep public class * extends android.app.Service
>
> -keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
>
> -keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
>
> -keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
>
> -keep public class com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService
>
> -keep public class * extends android.view.View {
>      public (android.content.Context);
>      public (android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
>      public (android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
>   }
>
> -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
>      public (android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
>   }
>
> -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
>      public (android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
>   }
>
> -keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
>      public void *(android.view.View);
>      public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
>   }
>
> -keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
>     public void *(android.view.View);
>   }
>
> -whyareyoukeeping

What do I need to remove Parse errors in Proguard?

Comment: looks like u got a 'PicturePlay.java' that has some syntax in it which you are not explicitly telling proguard to bypass.

Comment: There are Parse IDs that I want obfuscated, so I don't think I want to completely bypass Parse in those lines.  Any suggestions?

Comment: dont have to bypass entire class. it may have been flagged for something like an 'entry' pt or a callback or some special interface. gotta read..

Comment: Read where?  I posted all the output I know about.

Answer (score 0):

The `-whyareyoukeeping` option requires a class specification, example:

```
-whyareyoukeeping class com.example.**
```